# C# Insertion Order into List from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was surprised to see that I am having insertion order issues into a C# list when instantiating it from an Entity Framework Select.

I am creating multiple dtos which contain a `List<int>` of keys, but the insertion order is random per dto object. It's the weirdest thing. I thought that insertion order into C# lists was preserved, so I'm trying to figure out where the order is being determined.

**Server Code:**

```
var locations = Context.Location
        .Where(x => x.fk_LocationId == id)
        .Include(t => t.DoctorLocations);

Region.Locations = locations
        .SelectMany(x => x.DoctorLocations)
        .Where(y => y.fk_LocationId == id)
        .Select(x =>
            new SortableItem
            {
                Keys = new List<int> { x.fk_doctorId, x.fk_locationId },
                Type = "Practice",
                Priority = x.Priority ?? 0,
            })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Priority)
        .ToList();
```

**View:**

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.DoctorLocations.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Delete", "DoctorLocation" new { doctorId= Model.Locations[i].Keys[0], locationId= Model.Locations[i].Keys[1], }, null)
}
```

**Update Per @PaulAbbot**

I removed the `SelectMany` but get the same result. I also created more dto objects to look for a pattern in when they alternate. I don't see one, but they consistent in how they are returned from the server.

```
Region.Locations = Context.DoctorLocations
        .Where(y => (y.fk_doctorId == doctorId) &&
            locations.Select(x => x.locationId).Contains(y.fk_locationId))
        .Where(y => y.fk_doctorId == doctorid)
        .Select(x =>
            new SortableItem {
                Keys = new List<int> { x.fk_doctorId, x.fk_locationId }
            })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Priority)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Is it truly random?  It looks like your `SelectMany` may be throwing things off so it's subsorting by priority for each location instead of sorting by priority globally.  Are you getting 1-2-3-1-2-3 instead of 1-1-2-2-3-3?

Comment: It's tough to say, Keys = new List<int> { x.fk_doctorId, x.fk_locationId } will alternate between having the doctor be the first id, and having the location be the first id. I think you are right about the selectmany. I'll see if I can remove that and find another way for a test.

Comment: The query looks ok. What is the generated SQL?

Comment: That's a great question. Let me check.

Comment: Hmm, do you mean the order of the elements of the `Keys` list? Looks like there is a bug in EF processing such type of projection. I've just tried something similar and the SQL is simply wrong (latest EF6.1.3)

Comment: Thank you @IvanStoev. This really throws a wrench in my plans, but it's good to know. I'll have to be more explicit in how I'm assigning these keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug in EF6 processing projections containing constructs like `new List<int> { val1, val2, ...}`. Although it does not generate `NotSupportedException`, the generated SQL `ORDER BY` clause needed for correctly materializing the result is wrong (using a constant instead of a index selector expression).

In case you don't need `IQueryable<T>` result, I would suggest the usual *double projection* workaround - use normal anonymous type projection in LINQ to Entities query, then at the end switch to LINQ to Objects and do the desired projection:

```
var result = locations
    .SelectMany(x => x.DoctorLocations)
    .Where(y => y.fk_LocationId == id)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        K1 = x.fk_doctorId, K2 = x.fk_locationId,
        Type = "Practice",
        Priority = x.Priority ?? 0,
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Priority)
    .AsEnumerable() // switch to L2O
    .Select(x => new SortableItem
    {
        Keys = new List<int> { x.K1, x.K2 },
        Type = x.Type,
        Priority = x.Priority,
    })
    .ToList();
```

I know, annoying, but at least works as expected :)

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you, and thanks for explaining why it fixed the issue.